# Crystal reports 2011 formula to calculate a time interval and divide it

Tags: crystal-reports

I need a help, I need to calculate an interval of time in 1 hour and divide your result by 12.

I have a table in my database that receives data from date and time and a value field in a cycle of 5 minute in 5 minute cycle I have 12 values ​​in 1 hour. I need to sum ​​the values ​​of this period of 1 hour and divide its value by 12.

How could I do this using a formula of the crystal 2011? was trying to use the DateDiff passing a parameter interval of time to filter, but I had no success.

My parameter using the type Date and Time, Static, Allow range values​​.

DateDiff ("h", {TB_Dados.Timestamp}, {?MyParameterDateRange})

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to group your timestamps by hour.  Extend your datasource to include a field you can use to group by the timestamp's hour, something like yyyymmddhh.  All the timestamps with that same value (up to 12, in your case) need to be summed, then you can average them by dividing by 12, or using an aggregate function.

Comment: Groupings how not thought about it before, exact grouping by time I got my 12 records with a totalizer my field, just do not understand why you said to create another field in my data source. Now I need to do to divide the totalizers, Tank you Beth.

Comment: If you don't need to add another group, then it's even easier.

Comment: Beth just one more doubt, I grouped my timestamp field per hour and created a formula that takes this group and the sum divided by 12 so he got the expected result, I now need to add the result of the groups with the formula and show this result in the final report. ex: I filtered out a period of 4 hours so I have 4 groups with a field by dividing the sum of the group need one more field at the end of the report that shows the sum of the results of the groups shown, how can I do this?

Comment: You should be able to add a totals field outside the group footer and total the formula values.  Is that what you need?

Comment: I need to sum the result of this formula, Sum ({TB_Table1.Valor}, {TB_Table1.HoraRegistro}, "by hour") / 12 this formula returns the sum of the grouping by time and divide your result by 12. now I need to add a field totalizer that these results obtained by this formula. I am not able to think of a way to do this?

Comment: yes, so in your report footer, you can insert a summary field summing up the values of your formula across groups?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm not getting done, I'm trying to insert a summary, but do not know how to do this summary receive the result of my formula.

Comment: after you choose to insert a new summary field, it asks you for the field to summarize on.  you should pick your function, or if you're doing work outside a function you want to include in this summary, create a new function performing that work and summarize on your new function.